# Diferences between insert, save, update in MongoTemplate (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongotemplate

I am starting with Spring and MongoDB. I have seen that there are several methods to insert and / or update. I have also read some posts here explaining some concepts. But I don't quite understand them.
Correct me if I'm wrong or if things are missing.

- Update (): only updates an object and only works if it has an id.
- Upsert (): Makes an Update if the object exists (it must have an id) or inserts it if it does not exist.
- Insert (): You don't need an id and add a Document to the collection.
- save (): I don't really know the difference with an insert.

If there are more methods that work similarly and that I forgot to mention, I would appreciate if you could explain it as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Save**

The save method saves the document to collection for the entity type of the given object. When we pass collection name, then document is saved in the specified collection, even if entity is of different type.

`Student ram = new Student(101,"Ram",20);
mongoTemplate.save(ram);

Person newPerson = new Person(102, "Shyam");
mongoTemplate.save(newPerson, "student"); `

After Save
{ "_id" : 101, "name" : "Ram", "age" : 20, "_class" : "com.concretepage.entity.Student" }
{ "_id" : 102, "name" : "Shyam", "_class" : "com.concretepage.entity.Person" }

**Insert**

To insert a document into MongoDB collection, the MongoTemplate provides insert method. Find the code to insert one document.

Student ram = new Student(1,"Ram",20);
mongoTemplate.insert(ram);

After Insert
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Ram", "age" : 20, "_class" : "com.concretepage.entity.Student" }

for more info, Refer below link

https://www.concretepage.com/spring-5/spring-data-mongotemplate